# Excel UDF changing the smart tag error menu

Tags: excel, interop, vba

I would like to achieve what I show on this picture. Changing the cell Error smart tag menu options. 
Does anyone knows a way to do it (preferably from within the udf code) ?

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure you will have to change a .dll library on every instance of Excel you use and you will need to enable "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3" under Tools->References, which can be a pain if you're distributing your worksheet (basically, it can be done, I found something somewhere 3 years ago that helped me, but it is a lot more difficult than just clicking "Enable Content").  Can you use "On Error Goto ..." and use "Err.Number" to determine why the UDF returned an error, then return a custom error message to the cell that way?